# Python: Most efficient loop until condition

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements, infinite-loop

I have got to a point in my code where I need to do this:

```
while True:
  if first_number == second_number:
    do_something()
    break
```

The first number will keep incrementing beyond my control and I need to wait until this number reaches the value of the second number before I can continue.

I am looking for the best way to do this that will use up the least amount of resources (CPU).

Comment: Skip the loop and execute `first_number = second_number`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is called "busy waiting".  In order to do this without eating up CPU time, you should sleep for a short interval in each iteration of the loop:

```
while True:
  if first_number == second_number:
    do_something()
    break
  time.sleep(0.1)
```

Adjust the sleep interval as appropriate.

But there's likely a better way to accomplish what you want.  How is `first_number` changing value if it's "out of your control"?  Is your program receiving input?  Reading from a socket?  Are you sending a network request for data?  Is this data shared among processes using `multiprocessing`'s facilities?

Comment: This is one of the solutions that I've looked at but wanted to see if there were any others.

Comment: The actual problem I'm trying to solve currently is: first_number is current time position through a song and second_number is the total duration of the song.
I need to run some code when the song finishes but the built-in function to deal with this doesn't seem to be working (another question) and I was wondering about this anyway.

Comment: Still hard to recommend alternatives without knowing more about the use case (is the song playing in a subprocess? in a separate thread via some library function?).  In any case, use of `sleep` for this purpose is entirely standard.

Comment: Is there any way you can make the thing asynchronous? Might take the load of needing the loop in your user code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply check if first number is not equal to the second number, in the while loop's condition itself.

```
while first_number != second_number:
```

Comment: But won't this run the CPU at 100%?

Comment: The first number is beyond my control and will keep incrementing, I need to do something in my code once this reaches the value of the second number.

Comment: @A_Porcupine If the difference between `first_number` and `second_number` is too big, this is the best you could do :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
while first_number != second_number:
    #Do what you want
```